# My variable is always undefined, function returning before awaiting the query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
const express = require('express')
const usersJs = require('./endpoints/users')
var cors = require('cors')


const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

app.post('/addUser', (req, res) => {
      result = usersJs.doAddUser().then(result => console.log(result))
      res.json(result)

})
```

This is my server which is doing the call of doAdduser() from another file as you see bellow...

```
let stuff_i_want

module.exports.doAddUser = () => {

    return addUser(async function (result) {
        stuff_i_want = result;
        return stuff_i_want
    });
}


addUser = async (callback) => {


    const mysql = require('mysql')


    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        port: "",
        user: "",
        password: "",
        database: ""
    })
    connection.connect(async function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM USERS", async function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stuff_i_want = result
        });
    });
    return callback(result)
}
```

but the problem that result is always undefined in when im trying to res.json() it to the client, or when im trying console.log(result), its happening before addUser() which will make it undefined, tried with delay, with async await, but still result undefined in client and server but in doAdduser i can see the result from the database

Comment: Please post your code using await.

Comment: app.post('/addUser', async (req, res) => {

    result = await usersJs.doAddUser()
    console.log(result)
    res.json(result)
})
@SaachiTech

Comment: aven did return await from the doAddUser(), and await for the connection.query, aven tried the stuff_i_want = await result.
nothing worked and the app.post trying to console.log(result) and to res.json(result) before doing the doAddUser()

Comment: `doAddUser` isn't an async function. Also where is `addUser` define which you are executing from `module.exports.doAddUser` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna be honest with you, this code looks super messi. However i have an solution for you.

You try to get the result outside the promise chain, that dont work. I would use the modern way `async / await`

```
const express = require('express')
const { addUser } = require('./endpoints/users')
var cors = require('cors')


const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

app.post('/addUser', async (req, res) => {
   try {
      let result = await addUser();
      return res.status(200).json(result);
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" })
   }
})
```

Also wrap it with an `try / catch`

Next to your mysql connection:

```
const mysql = rquire("mysql");

module.exports.addUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      port: "",
      user: "",
      password: "",
      database: ""
    });
    connection.connect(err => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM USERS", (err, result) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

import it on the top not somehwere in the middle of the code this is just confusing.

export a named module called `addUser` witch is an function.

That function returns an promise.

Then reject on errors and resolve if you got an result from your DB.

The try / catch block will catch the error.

Also add an status code to your response. I am not sure here i might be wrong but no status code means your request was successful even if something went wrong on the serverside

Its also good to have an router folder where you add all your routes and import the route handlers in there that looks something like this then:

```
const { addUserHandler } = require("./user");
router.post("/addUser", addUserHandler)
```

So routes and the logic are seperated and it doesnt look messi

Comment: it worked the way you wrote thank you very much, sorry for the messi code but iv been stuck in this part trying for more than 2 weeks, so i tried every possible idea.